# I am wanting to check whether there is time overlap on a data table

Tags: excel

I am working on an excel task where I had to find out if there are overlapping dates.

In my excel worksheet there are columns for Session Date (col B) Session start time (Col C) Session end time (Col D) startDate(column D), from this I had to determine if there is an overlapping session times on the same date.

I have tired INDEX and Match functions, but dont know how to account for multple instances of the same date in comumn B

```
Date of Treatment   Pre-Treatment Time  Post-Treatment Time
28/03/2018  09:15   09:29
28/03/2018  10:42   11:07
28/03/2018  15:10   15:19
16/01/2018  10:51   11:02
30/08/2018  09:16   09:32
30/08/2018  09:51   10:15
30/08/2018  11:15   11:26
30/08/2018  14:23   14:36
30/08/2018  14:59   16:01
30/08/2018  17:18   17:28
```

I want to be able to flag sessions where there is an overlap or say they are fine

Answer (score 0):

Try sorting your data by date then start time, then if the start time of the second entry is lower than the previous row's end time, you know they are overlapping.

Comment: I cant sort the data, as the table is set into named areas for other functions to run from and I believe if I sort it will break those?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to use MAX and MIN functions to check that and return the overlap. And throw it inside a IF function to return overlp or not.

Try this:

1. Date of Treatment on A1 and the rest of the info on the following columns.
2. On D1 write "Check"
3. On G1 name the range as "start"
4. On G2 name the range as end

After you set up put the fomrula in D2 and drag to the end of the range.
=IF(MAX(MIN(end;A2)-MAX(start;A2)+1;0)=0;"Not overlap";"Overlaps")

To acomplish what you wnat you need to delimit the date and you do that by using the named ranges START and END.

Below is an image of the table I tested.

[SCREEN TEST FORMULA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFV9i.gif)

Hope it helps!

Let me know if you managed the problem!

Comment: Thanks for this, almost there I think. Just not following the G1, G2 instruction?

Comment: I am naming the start time and end time columns right, then what goes int eh G cells?

Comment: And I am not sure this is working. The overlap check is once you have identified the same day. EG your screen shot shows an ovelap in cell D5, but on the 30/08 there are no time slots that overlap the session time of 10:51 - 11:02 - I dont think?

Comment: On G1 and G2 you put the dates to be checked against your dates. For instance, if you wnat to know if a patient was in treatment between 01/03 and 01/04/2018 it will return just the 2 first sets as overlapping.

Comment: "...EG your screen shot shows an ovelap in cell D5, but on the 30/08 there are no time slots that overlap the session time of 10:51 - 11:02 - I dont think?" So you need to check if the date overlap and ALSO the times?

Comment: Yes also the times. So a) are two sessions on the same day? if yes, do the session times overlap?

Comment: Ah! OK, I see now. It is the Shift Conundrum that many folks deal with. I won´t be able to step you through the solution right now, but you can piggyback from this one: [link](https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/calculate-overlapping-time-in-excel.16316/). I hope you get the solution!

Comment: Thank Diogo - Appreciated